# Haskell: Pure data structure that efficiently models a block of memory?

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I'm interested in writing a virtual machine that works with a block of memory. I'd like to model the block of memory (say 1MB) with a pure data structure that's still efficient to reads and writes anywhere within the block. Not very interested in a mutable structure. Does such a structure exist?

Comment: Maybe a `Map` from indices to `Int32`? You could leave out the initial zeros for compactness.

Comment: What's wrong with e.g. `STUArray`s? They're efficient and safe (unless you decide to use them unsafely).

Comment: @DanielFischer maybe "Not very interested in a mutable structure" is what is wrong with it.

Comment: @luqui I just wonder why and asked to find out.

Answer (score 8):

The [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package offers immutable (and mutable) boxed and unboxed vectors, with all the time complexities you'd expect. The mutable ones are usable from both IO and ST, and you can have an unboxed array of any instance of Storable. It's a lot nicer than the standard array modules.

However, since you mentioned efficient immutable updates, I would suggest using a Map-like data structure; perhaps a HashMap from [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers). It might even be worthwhile to have a map with small unboxed vectors at the leaves, to avoid some tree overhead.

Depending on your use-case, you might also be interested in the standard [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html), which has O(1) access to the beginning and end, and pretty good access times into the middle of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Is [Data.Array.ST](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/array/Data-Array-ST.html) good enough for you?

Comment: He explicitely stated that he is interested in an immutable data structure.

Comment: @Niklas the username 'Ana' suggests it might be a she.

Comment: @Daniel: Absolutely! I should really condition myself to use "he or she" more often.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark I think it's reasonable to suggest that maybe one doesn't want to use an immutable data structure here.  If the VM in questions is intended to execute a *strict sequence* of operations that mutate state, an implementation that uses an ST-based mutable array strikes me as the best choice—it has the requisite semantics.  I'd only want to go to an immutable data structure if I was going to do something special, like a non-deterministic VM or a VM with facilities for "rewinding" the state or such.  (Simple user-driven stepping can be done by using mutable arrays in the IO monad.)